# Navbar conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

So im currently trying to figure out how I can change the state of a button depending on wether I'm on the page or not.

I have this navbar:

```
import { Fragment } from 'react'
import { Disclosure, Menu, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { BellIcon, MenuIcon, XIcon } from '@heroicons/react/outline'
import { PlusSmIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'



const user = {
  name: 'Tom Cook',
  email: 'tom@example.com',
  imageUrl:
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',
}
const navigation = [
  { name: 'Home', href: '/', current: true },
  { name: 'Dashboard', href: '/dashboard', current: false },
  { name: 'Price', href: '/price', current: false },
]
const userNavigation = [
  { name: 'Your Profile', href: '/profile' },
  { name: 'Settings', href: '#' },
  { name: 'Sign out', href: '#' },
]

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
}

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <Disclosure as="nav" className="bg-gray-800">
      {({ open }) => (
        <>
          <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div className="flex justify-between h-16">
              <div className="flex">
                <div className="-ml-2 mr-2 flex items-center md:hidden">
                  {/* Mobile menu button */}
                  <Disclosure.Button className="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-white">
                    <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                    {open ? (
                      <XIcon className="block h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                    ) : (
                      <MenuIcon className="block h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                    )}
                  </Disclosure.Button>
                </div>
                <div className="flex-shrink-0 flex items-center">
                  <img
                    className="block lg:hidden h-8 w-auto"
                    src="Assets/img/logo-light.png"
                    alt="Nemondo"
                  />
                  <img
                    className="hidden lg:block h-8 w-auto"
                    src="Assets/img/logo-light.png"
                    alt="Nemondo"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="hidden md:ml-6 md:flex md:items-center md:space-x-4">
                  {navigation.map((item) => (
                    <a
                      key={item.name}
                      href={item.href}
                      className={classNames(
                        item.current ? 'bg-gray-900 text-white' : 'text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white',
                        'px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium'
                      )}
                      aria-current={item.current ? 'page' : undefined}
                    >
                      {item.name}
                    </a>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="flex items-center">
                <div className="flex-shrink-0">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-500 hover:bg-indigo-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-indigo-500"
                  >
                    <PlusSmIcon className="-ml-1 mr-2 h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
                    <span>New Job</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div className="hidden md:ml-4 md:flex-shrink-0 md:flex md:items-center">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="bg-gray-800 p-1 rounded-full text-gray-400 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white"
                  >
                    <span className="sr-only">View notifications</span>
                    <BellIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                  </button>

                  {/* Profile dropdown */}
                  <Menu as="div" className="ml-3 relative">
                    <div>
                      <Menu.Button className="bg-gray-800 flex text-sm rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white">
                        <span className="sr-only">Open user menu</span>
                        <img className="h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src={user.imageUrl} alt="" />
                      </Menu.Button>
                    </div>
                    <Transition
                      as={Fragment}
                      enter="transition ease-out duration-200"
                      enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                      enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                      leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                      leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                      leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                    >
                      <Menu.Items className="origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg py-1 bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none z-10">
                        {userNavigation.map((item) => (
                          <Menu.Item key={item.name}>
                            {({ active }) => (
                              <a
                                href={item.href}
                                className={classNames(
                                  active ? 'bg-gray-100' : '',
                                  'block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700'
                                )}
                              >
                                {item.name}
                              </a>
                            )}
                          </Menu.Item>
                        ))}
                      </Menu.Items>
                    </Transition>
                  </Menu>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <Disclosure.Panel className="md:hidden">
            <div className="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1 sm:px-3">
              {navigation.map((item) => (
                <Disclosure.Button
                  key={item.name}
                  as="a"
                  href={item.href}
                  className={classNames(
                    item.current ? 'bg-gray-900 text-white' : 'text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white',
                    'block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium'
                  )}
                  aria-current={item.current ? 'page' : undefined}
                >
                  {item.name}
                </Disclosure.Button>
              ))}
            </div>
            <div className="pt-4 pb-3 border-t border-gray-700">
              <div className="flex items-center px-5 sm:px-6">
                <div className="flex-shrink-0">
                  <img className="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src={user.imageUrl} alt="" />
                </div>
                <div className="ml-3">
                  <div className="text-base font-medium text-white">{user.name}</div>
                  <div className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-400">{user.email}</div>
                </div>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="ml-auto flex-shrink-0 bg-gray-800 p-1 rounded-full text-gray-400 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white"
                >
                  <span className="sr-only">View notifications</span>
                  <BellIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="mt-3 px-2 space-y-1 sm:px-3">
                {userNavigation.map((item) => (
                  <Disclosure.Button
                    key={item.name}
                    as="a"
                    href={item.href}
                    className="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700"
                  >
                    {item.name}
                  </Disclosure.Button>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          </Disclosure.Panel>
        </>
      )}
    </Disclosure>
  )
}
```

It seems that when I change the current:

```
const navigation = [
  { name: 'Home', href: '/', current: true },
  { name: 'Dashboard', href: '/dashboard', current: false },
  { name: 'Price', href: '/price', current: false },
```

From true to false and vice versa it does exactly what I need, but how can I make it so it changes depending on whether I'm on the page or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use `react-router-dom` for the path routing? if yes, it is a good choice to use `useLocation` to check your `href` value against current route. doc: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation

Comment: Yes i am using the V6. I will check the doc.

Comment: Sadly im still having a hard time making this work.

Comment: Let me give you a simple example.

Comment: I would really appriciate that! (:

Answer (score 1):

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/navbar-react-router-dom-v6-p8vy4b

It is not styled very good. The conditional check of current route look like this:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const navigation = [
    {
      name: "Root",
      href: "/"
    },
    {
      name: "Home",
      href: "/home"
    },
    {
      name: "About",
      href: "/about"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <navbar
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        height: "50px",
        backgroundColor: "red",
        width: "100vw"
      }}
    >
      {navigation.map((nav, idx) => {
        const isActiveRoute = location.pathname === nav.href;
        // const isActiveRoute = location.pathname.startsWith(nav.href) // or if you want a prefix instead
        return (
          <a
            key={idx}
            href={nav.href}
            style={{ padding: "0 25px", color: isActiveRoute && "black" }}
          >
            <h3>{nav.name}</h3>
          </a>
        );
      })}
    </navbar>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

and the routing :

```
import "./styles.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

export default function App() {
  const wrapNavbar = (item) => {
    return (
      <>
        <Navbar />
        {item}
        <p>note: black navbar color is the active item</p>
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={wrapNavbar(<h1>this is root </h1>)} />
        <Route path="/home" element={wrapNavbar(<h1>this is home </h1>)} />
        <Route path="/about" element={wrapNavbar(<h1>this is about </h1>)} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: I will try and follow this, but your function and export default seem to be opposite of how I did it.

Comment: Ohh about that, it's just my habit writing ES6, `export default functionName() {}` can be written `export default const functionName = () => {}`, well and the export default can be drag on other line.